# Querying PostGIS and OSM to get only major stations and subway of UK?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, united-kingdom

I am working with Great Britain OSM data. I have read the classification of UK railway stations. There are a lot of classes in there such as subway entrance, halt, station and many others. I want to get only the major stations and subway of UK. I am using the following Query but it is not returning all station points. I have compared the result with OSM maps service.

```
SELECT way, name, railway from planet_osm_point WHERE railway IN ('station', 'halt', 'entrance') AND name is not null
```

What more types should I include?

Comment: I would guess `halt` is too small to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently only querying the points table. Railway stations might as well be mapped as polygons.

A good strategy to get all commonly used OSM tags is to display your data on top of an openstreetmap background (e.g. with the openlayers plugin in QGIS), and look for missing stations.

You can install the JOSM editor, zoom to the missing object, download the data and look at the given tags. You don't even need to sign up for that.

[Overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) is another method to get and display filtered OSM data. Move the map to the wanted area, and enter `railway station` in the wizards input form.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:railway%3Dstation it seems that the *new* tag is `public_transport=station` though it is hard to see if that is a recent change or not.